# Ok to Require Contact Form Submission to View Page?

Tags: interaction-design, contact-us

I have a product website going live soon.  One of the pages is a list of case studies on previous customers.

Is it good UX to have a "contact me" modal that is required to be submitted before a visitor can view my case studies?  I don't want to annoy my visitors, but generating conversations is important to me.

Comment: The more barriers you put up, the fewer people will complete the journey. It's kind of up to you whether you feel that capturing some contact details for whatever reason are more important than having people anonymously reading casestudies. Also - depending where this site is, you may need to comply with GDPR regulations, meaning you need to have a good reason for requesting their contact details.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer: NO**

Your case studies should be the evidence you're using to convince people to pay for your product.

If your customers cannot view the reason for buying your product without giving away their details why would they bother.

**OR**

You: Here's our product

Customer: Great what does it do?

You: Give me your phone number and email then I'll tell you

Customer: ...

Comment: I follow that.  Thank you for your answer.  Are there specific UX principles or guidelines about requiring contact forms/personal info, etc.?  Perhaps I can use those to design a better strategy for collecting that information.

Comment: @trademark By all means _ask_ for contact details ("_If you would like us to send more info / contact you..._") but I wouldn't insist on it... Unless committed for other reasons, I've often moved on to other sites when faced with a compulsory contact form.

Comment: @trademark I don't know of any specific UX principles that I could provide as reference, for your situation, but I would say that providing the evidence first builds user buy in and makes them more likely to complete a form for further information.

As for the UX principles for form design here are some useful resources:
[UX Planet](https://uxplanet.org/the-18-must-do-principles-in-the-form-design-fe89d0127c92)
[Norman Neilson](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/web-form-design/)